# Numbering rows based on vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame such as this:

```
`example=data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                Chemical= c("206/320.0481mz/12.85min","90/315.1582mz/29.20min",
                                             "40/289.1410mz/23.88min",
                                             "463/406.0850mz/24.50min",
                                             "534/386.1587mz/9.14min","455/427.0640mz/24.49min",
                                             "538/355.1407mz/17.01min",
                                             "498/252.1577mz/13.64min",
                                             "155/1123.1124mz/4.87min","366/305.1566mz/24.49min",
                                             "179/273.1133mz/21.54min",
                                             "436/421.1523mz/19.35min",
                                             "260/509.2528mz/27.41min",
                                             "261/511.2664mz/24.52min","39/289.1411mz/23.45min",
                                             "315/251.1647mz/27.99min",
                                             "344/509.2533mz/27.54min",
                                             "406/769.0885mz/10.47min","27/273.1148mz/28.78min"),
                                     ind = c("ARBObr1434_1-4_01_2857.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1435_1-5_01_2858.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1437_1-7_01_2860.mzXML","ARBObr1438_1-8_01_2861.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1439_1-9_01_2862.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1441_1-11_01_2864.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1442_1-12_01_2865.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1442_1-12_01_2865.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1442_1-12_01_2865.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1445_1-15_01_2868.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1445_1-15_01_2868.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1446_1-16_01_2869.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1450_1-20_01_2874.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1450_1-20_01_2874.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1451_1-21_01_2875.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1451_1-21_01_2875.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1453_1-23_01_2877.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1453_1-23_01_2877.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1453_1-23_01_2877.mzXML"),
                              tratamento = c("C","C","C","C",
                                             "C","C","P","P","P","P","P",
                                             "P","P","P","P","P","NP","NP",
                                             "NP"),
                                   value= c(68184.5031,
                                             1057909.969,1334458.76,375629.295,
                                             261687.1145,193524.05,526918.865,
                                             336500.26,1298296.858,159774.415,
                                             59492.945,183294.91,20815203.75,705.84,
                                             11386.515,943224.495,
                                             14736362.24,476615.194,2974523.025))`
```

In the column "Chemical" I have different chemical compounds and in the column "ind" I have the respective individuals I sampled. For each individual I have multiple identified compounds, so for example I have two rows for "ARBObr1450_1-20_01_2874.mzXML", one for each compound I found. I would like to create another column in which always when the value "ARBObr1450_1-20_01_2874.mzXML" is found in "ind", the value would be the same, irrespective of the "Chemical" column, and each individual would have one value.

So I'd end with a table like this:

```
  `example=data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                Chemical= c("206/320.0481mz/12.85min","90/315.1582mz/29.20min",
                                             "40/289.1410mz/23.88min",
                                             "463/406.0850mz/24.50min",
                                             "534/386.1587mz/9.14min","455/427.0640mz/24.49min",
                                             "538/355.1407mz/17.01min",
                                             "498/252.1577mz/13.64min",
                                             "155/1123.1124mz/4.87min","366/305.1566mz/24.49min",
                                             "179/273.1133mz/21.54min",
                                             "436/421.1523mz/19.35min",
                                             "260/509.2528mz/27.41min",
                                             "261/511.2664mz/24.52min","39/289.1411mz/23.45min",
                                             "315/251.1647mz/27.99min",
                                             "344/509.2533mz/27.54min",
                                             "406/769.0885mz/10.47min","27/273.1148mz/28.78min"),
                                     ind = c("ARBObr1434_1-4_01_2857.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1435_1-5_01_2858.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1437_1-7_01_2860.mzXML","ARBObr1438_1-8_01_2861.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1439_1-9_01_2862.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1441_1-11_01_2864.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1442_1-12_01_2865.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1442_1-12_01_2865.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1442_1-12_01_2865.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1445_1-15_01_2868.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1445_1-15_01_2868.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1446_1-16_01_2869.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1450_1-20_01_2874.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1450_1-20_01_2874.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1451_1-21_01_2875.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1451_1-21_01_2875.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1453_1-23_01_2877.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1453_1-23_01_2877.mzXML",
                                             "ARBObr1453_1-23_01_2877.mzXML"),
                              tratamento = c("C","C","C","C",
                                             "C","C","P","P","P","P","P",
                                             "P","P","P","P","P","NP","NP",
                                             "NP"),
                                   value= c(68184.5031,
                                             1057909.969,1334458.76,375629.295,
                                             261687.1145,193524.05,526918.865,
                                             336500.26,1298296.858,159774.415,
                                             59492.945,183294.91,20815203.75,705.84,
                                             11386.515,943224.495,
                                             14736362.24,476615.194,2974523.025),
                                   new_column = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,
                                             7L,7L,7L,8L,8L,9L,10L,10L,
                                             11L,11L,12L,12L,12L))`
```

How can I achieve this? The entire data frame has about 28,000 rows, so it would be awesome to do this in R...
I tried creating a vector with unique indvidual names, but don't know how to proceed and I don't even know if this is the best way to go. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can create a new column as `as.numeric(factor(example$ind))`.

Comment: `data.table::rleid(example$ind)` Or `match(example$ind, unique(example$ind))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rle`, i.e.

```
i1 <- rle(example$ind)
rep(seq(i1$lengths), i1$lengths)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  7  7  8  8  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 12
```